# Why the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $E$ be a Hausdorff topological space and $K$ is a compact set $K$ of $E$.

Why if any sequence $\{x_n\}$ of $K$  satisfies the property that every subsequence contains a convergent subsequence converging to the same limit $x$, then $\{x_n\}$ itself converges to $x$?

Comment: Hausdorff and compact are irrelevant here. This is a general fact for topological convergences.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x_n$ does not converge to $x$. Then there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that whatever $n_0$ you take there is at least one $n >n_0$ such that $x_n \not \in U$. This implies that there exist $n_1<n_2<...$ such that $x_{n_k} \notin U$ for any $k$. Now can you see that no subsequence of $(x_{n_k})$ can converge to $x$?